# ReferenceError: cannot access 'CONTRACT' before initialization

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript, ganache

I'm trying to test a single smart contract (PCE_Contract.sol) with (PCE_Contract_test.js) using Truffle. When I run Truffle test, console output is :

`ReferenceError: Cannot access 'PCE_Contract' before initialization`

PCE_Contract_test.js:

```
const PCE_Contract = artifacts.require("./PCE_Contract");

contract('PCE_Contract', () => {

it('should deploy SC properly', async() => {

  const PCE_Contract = await PCE_Contract.deployed();

  console.log(PCE_Contract.address);

  assert(PCE_Contract !== '');

});

});
```

PCE_Contract.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract PCE_Contract {

  uint256 public LOCK_PERIOD  = 365 days;
  address public investor;

  mapping(address => Deposit) deposits;

  constructor(){
  
  investor = msg.sender;
  }

  struct Deposit {
      uint256 value;
      uint256 releaseTime;
  }

  function investment() public payable {
       require(msg.value > 0,
         "You must make a non-zero deposit.");

       if (deposits[investor].releaseTime == 0) {
           uint256 releaseTime = block.timestamp + LOCK_PERIOD;
           deposits[investor] = Deposit(msg.value, releaseTime);

       } else {
           deposits[investor].value += msg.value;
       }
   }

   function withdraw() public {

    require(deposits[investor].value > 0,
      "You have no deposits available.");

    require(deposits[msg.sender].releaseTime < block.timestamp,
      "Your lock period has not ended yet.");

    msg.sender.transfer(deposits[investor].value);

    deposits[msg.sender].value = 0;
    deposits[msg.sender].releaseTime = 0;
}

function getDeposit(address holder) public view
  returns (uint256 value, uint256 releaseTime)

  {
        return(deposits[holder].value, deposits[holder].releaseTime);
    }

}
```

Truffle v5.1.49 (core: 5.1.49)
Solidity - ^0.7.0 (solc-js)
Node v12.18.4
Web3.js v1.2.1

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Change `PCE_Contract.deployed()` to `PCE_Contract.new()`.

Comment: Side note: `assert(PCE_Contract !== '')` is useless.

Comment: @goodvibration still not working

Comment: Then the problem is probably in your migration script (I'd suggest you simply delete it).

Comment: @goodvibrations That didn’t solve the problem either, I assume you don’t see any problem with the contract.sol & test.js files ? Trying to narrow down my options.

Comment: Well, you should also get rid of the `./` prefix in `artifacts.require("./PCE_Contract")`, because Truffle imports the contract from the JSON file generated by the compiler, not from the Solidity file where your contract's source code is located. But I don't think that this should cause any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
const PCE_Contract = artifacts.require("./PCE_Contract");
...
{
    const PCE_Contract = await PCE_Contract.deployed();
    ...
}
```

The second declaration of `PCE_Contract` masks the first declaration of `PCE_Contract`.

So you are essentially attempting to use variable `PCE_Contract` before it has been declared (exactly as the error-message tells you).

If you placed these two declarations in the same scope, then you would get the error before the script was even executed. But since you placed them in two different scopes, the script was eligible for execution (and subsequently, the error did not occur before execution, only during execution).

---

**Side note:**

You can get rid of the `./` prefix in `artifacts.require("./PCE_Contract")`, because Truffle imports the artifacts from the JSON files generated by the compiler, not from the Solidity files where your actual source code is located (hence relative paths are not required in `artifacts.require` statements).

Comment: Kind sir, Thank you so much. Commenting out second declaration solved my problem.

Comment: @newbnoob: Glad to hear that. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it.

Comment: @newbnoob: BTW, I don't quite see how commenting out the second declaration helps you with getting the test to complete successfully. You need to **rename** the variable in the second declaration.